# Python: write a wav file into numpy float array

Tags: python, numpy, wav

```
ifile = wave.open("input.wav")
```

how can I write this file into a numpy float array now?

Comment: @JoranBeasley it has to be float.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
>>> from scipy.io.wavfile import read
>>> a = read("adios.wav")
>>> numpy.array(a[1],dtype=float)
array([ 128.,  128.,  128., ...,  128.,  128.,  128.])
```

Typically it would be bytes which are then ints... here we just convert it to float type.

You can read about read here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html#module-scipy.io.wavfile

Comment: thanks! one more question, how could I do this for all .wav-files in the current working directory? I mean saving each file in a cycle in an array, and concentrating it by the end of each step to a main array?

Answer (score 24):

Seven years after the question was asked...

```
import wave
import numpy

# Read file to get buffer                                                                                               
ifile = wave.open("input.wav")
samples = ifile.getnframes()
audio = ifile.readframes(samples)

# Convert buffer to float32 using NumPy                                                                                 
audio_as_np_int16 = numpy.frombuffer(audio, dtype=numpy.int16)
audio_as_np_float32 = audio_as_np_int16.astype(numpy.float32)

# Normalise float32 array so that values are between -1.0 and +1.0                                                      
max_int16 = 2**15
audio_normalised = audio_as_np_float32 / max_int16
```

Comment: How should I install the `wave` module? `pip install wave`?

Comment: @Unsigned_Arduino Have you just tried it?  According to the docs, the wave module has been part of Python since at least version 2.7, and it's still included in version 3.8: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/wave.html

Comment: Just tried it, it's included. I never seen this module before so I questioned it's existance in the PSL.

Comment: Hi Matthew Walker, thanks for such a nice answer. I want to ask, that the size of audio_normalised is twice that of samples, so is it representing data for 2 channels, or sth else, please can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question. By size do you mean the length in bytes perhaps? If that’s the case then I suspect the answer lies in the int16 (2 byte) representation of the PCM in a wave file. Does that answer your question?

Comment: How to know if we should use `int16` or `int32` in `frombuffer`? Any wave file attributes to tell?

Comment: Oh, I think `wave.getsampwidth` is the value for `int16` or `int32` in `frombuffer`, right?

Comment: @avocado [getsampwidth()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_read.getsampwidth) returns the sample width in bytes, so 2 bytes => `int16`, or 4 bytes => `int32`.  I guess I just hadn't come across WAV files with anything other than 2 bytes per sample.  Good point.

Comment: I wrote a more detailed answer on how to get a `numpy` array from a `wav` file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71042208/13180090) taking into account the sample width and channels. Although I haven't experimented with the normalization so I won't add it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 11):

Use `librosa` package and simply load wav file to numpy array with:

```
y, sr = librosa.load(filename)
```

> loads and decodes the audio as a time series y, represented as a
> one-dimensional NumPy floating point array. The variable sr contains
> the sampling rate of y, that is, the number of samples per second of
> audio. By default, all audio is mixed to mono and resampled to 22050
> Hz at load time. This behavior can be overridden by supplying
> additional arguments to librosa.load().

More information at [Librosa library documentation](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.load.html#librosa.load)

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough reputation to comment underneath @Matthew Walker 's answer, so I make a new answer to add an observation to Matt's answer. `max_int16` should be `2**15-1` not `2**15`.

Better yet, I think the normalization line should be replaced with:

```
audio_normalised = audio_as_np_float32 / numpy.iinfo(numpy.int16).max
```

If the audio is stereo (i.e. two channels) the left right values are interleaved, so to get the stereo array the following can be used :

```
channels = ifile.getnchannels()
audio_stereo = np.empty((int(len(audio_normalised)/channels), channels))
audio_stereo[:,0] = audio_normalised[range(0,len(audio_normalised),2)]
audio_stereo[:,1] = audio_normalised[range(1,len(audio_normalised),2)]
```

I believe this answers @Trees question in the comments section.

Comment: The issue with the definition of `max_int16` is interesting.  The range of 16 bit integers is -32,768 to 32,767.  If we want to scale from -1 to 1 then we want to divide by the largest possible value, in an absolute sense, or 32,768, which is `2**15`.  Hence the definition of `max_int16` in my answer.