# How to get numpy arrays output of .wav file format

Tags: python, numpy, wav

I am new to Python, and I am trying to train my audio voice recognition model. I want to read a .wav file and get output of that .wav file into Numpy arrays. How can I do that?

Comment: Something like this: [`scipy.io.wavfile.read`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) ?

Answer (score 6):

In keeping with @Marco's comment, you can have a look at the Scipy library and, in particular, at `scipy.io`.

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
```

To read your file ('filename.wav'), simply do

```
output = wavfile.read('filename.wav')
```

This will output a tuple (which I named 'output'):

- `output[0]`, the sampling rate
- `output[1]`, the sample array you want to analyze

Comment: from scipy.io import wavfile                                                                                      
output = wavfile.read('filename.wav'), with this would i get the numpy-array??

Comment: Yes, output[1] is an np.array with sound amplitudes (with as many readings per second as indicated by your sample rate, output[0]).

Answer (score 5):

This is possible with a few lines with `wave` (built in) and `numpy` (obviously). You don't need to use `librosa`, `scipy` or `soundfile`. The latest gave me problems reading `wav` files and it's the whole reason I'm writting here now.

```py
import numpy as np
import wave

# Start opening the file with wave
with wave.open('filename.wav') as f:
    # Read the whole file into a buffer. If you are dealing with a large file
    # then you should read it in blocks and process them separately.
    buffer = f.readframes(f.getnframes())
    # Convert the buffer to a numpy array by checking the size of the sample
    # width in bytes. The output will be a 1D array with interleaved channels.
    interleaved = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=f'int{f.getsampwidth()*8}')
    # Reshape it into a 2D array separating the channels in columns.
    data = np.reshape(interleaved, (-1, f.getnchannels()))
```

I like to pack it into a function that returns the sampling frequency and works with `pathlib.Path` objects. In this way it can be played using `sounddevice`

```py
# play_wav.py
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import wave

from typing import Tuple
from pathlib import Path


# Utility function that reads the whole `wav` file content into a numpy array
def wave_read(filename: Path) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, int]:
    with wave.open(str(filename), 'rb') as f:
        buffer = f.readframes(f.getnframes())
        inter = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=f'int{f.getsampwidth()*8}')
        return np.reshape(inter, (-1, f.getnchannels())), f.getframerate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Play all files in the current directory
    for wav_file in Path().glob('*.wav'):
        print(f"Playing {wav_file}")
        data, fs = wave_read(wav_file)
        sd.play(data, samplerate=fs, blocking=True)
```